# Active status of custom added top-menu items [Magento topmenu]

Tags: jquery, css, magento

To add "HOME" menu item and other after the categories menu items : in file `project\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml` by adding two blocks `home-link` and `post-menu-links`

```
<nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-link')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('post-menu-links')->toHtml(); ?>
        </ol>
</nav>
```

And this successfully adds menu items as accordingly Now how to maintain its active state like adding a "active" class on the active menu item added via these blocks ?

**What i tried**

I tried using via jquery cookies on click setting menu(li) index in jquery cookies. But it fails

- when clicking and stopping to load
- or coming later on the site (previous cookies being active active sign on wrong menu item.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template file:

> project\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml

If the links lead to CMS pages, you should find out the current page identifier.

```
<li id="the-cms-link">
    <a href="/the-cms-link">The CMS Link</a>
</li>

//Then in the PHP below the menu:
<script>
    var currentPageId = '';

    <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')): ?>
        currentPageId = '<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier(); ?>';
    <?php endif; ?>

    if (jQuery('#'+currentPageId).is('li')) {
        jQuery('#'+currentPageId).addClass('active');
    }
</script>
```

You can do this with the Page ID also, but remember that you need to setup the **<li> ID** from your CMS block.

In case you are using different links, such as ones from custom modules, you need to find out the current module, controller and action and check if they match any of the links then use jQuery again to set the active class.
To get the current module, controller and action:

```
$moduleName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$controllerName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add CMS-page menu items to active class.

In this Topmenu i have added CMS-links Block and it display with Static Block.

I have to create jQuery for add active claas in url

```
<?php if ($block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block-name')->toHtml()) { ?>
    <div class="top-menu-nav">
        <ul>
            <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block-name')->toHtml(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<!-- Add custom block Active urls -->

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    var url = window.location.href; //sets the variable "url" to the pathname of the current window
    var lastChar = url.substr(url.length - 1); 
    if(lastChar == "/") {url = url.substring(0, url.length-1);}
    //console.log(url);
    $('.top-menu-nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.top-menu-nav a').each(function () { 
        url2 = $(this).attr('href');
        if(url2.substr(url2.length - 1) == "/"){ url2 = url2.substring(0, url2.length-1);  } 
        //console.log(url2);
        if(url2 == url){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```